# Syntax errors while trying to make a foreign key sqlit3 p

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a foreign key to show which homework a student has been set. I have done what I believed to be the right syntax, however I keep getting syntax errors for other parts of the database. I'm not sure if this is because of the foreign key as it hasn't occured otherwise.

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HomeworkInfo (
            HWID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            HomeworkName text);""")

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HomeworkSet (
            HWID text,
            FOREIGN KEY (HWID) REFERENCES HomeworkInfo(HWID),
            FName text,
            SName text,
            Results text);""")



line 36, in <module>
    Results text);""")

    OperationalError: near "FName": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the definition of the foreign key at the end of the statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HomeworkSet (
            HWID text,
            FName text,
            SName text,
            Results text,
            FOREIGN KEY (HWID) REFERENCES HomeworkInfo(HWID)
            );
```

or define it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HomeworkSet (
            HWID text REFERENCES HomeworkInfo(HWID),
            FName text,
            SName text,
            Results text
            );
```

You can find more about the definition of the foreign keys here: [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but in your example it looks like `HomeworkInfo.HWID` is an `integer` but `HomeworkSet.HWID` is `text`. Shouldn't they be the same type?

Comment: SQLite is not at all strict with the data types: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sPgMcqbzW1W4xBMvk9mCmR/0

Comment: Wild! I had no idea. Thanks, forpas!